W/StorageTask : unable to change internal state to: INTERNAL_STATE_CANCELED, INTERNAL_STATE_CANCELING isUser: true from state:INTERNAL_STATE_SUCCESS
I am getting this error in flutter project, while Downloading the image to firebase.

Error:
[1] W/StorageTask( 5144): unable to change internal state to: INTERNAL_STATE_CANCELED, INTERNAL_STATE_CANCELING isUser: true from state:INTERNAL_STATE_SUCCESS

My code:
uploadImage(mImageFile) async {
     storageRef.Reference reference =
        storageRef.FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child("menus");
    storageRef.UploadTask uploadTask =
        reference.child(uniqueIDName + ".jpg").putFile(mImageFile);

    storageRef.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot = await uploadTask.whenComplete(() {});

    String downloadURL = await taskSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
    return downloadURL;
 }


It should download the image URL to firebase database

Yes, it's a common problem just wait for uploading that image.
await reference.child(uniqueIDName + ".jpg").putFile(mImageFile);

Similar question see here
